# Route message to queue based on one of the message's properties as routing key

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a microservice `A` that publishes messages to an exchange `E`. Each one of those messages contain in one of its json-representation fields a property which I want to use as a routing key.

For example, if `E` has queues `Q1` (which receives routing key `R1`), `Q2` (`R2`) and `Q3` (`R3`) bound to it, and message `M` was published to exchange `E` with routing key `R2` in one its properties, I would like `Q2` to get `M`.

However, I do not wish to explicitly send the message with a routing key from microservice `A` but to send it as is.

I was looking into rabbit plugins or exchange to exchange bindings to find a way to do it but couldn't find something of that sort without implementing another microservice that only routes the messages.

I would love to hear suggestions on how to do so based on existing tools.

Comment: Did you look into Header Exchange , A headers exchange routes messages based on arguments containing headers and optional values.